# How do I resolve a 0x7B stop error on my XP installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, bsod

I have partitioned my 500GB hard drive, allowing me 50GB for Windows XP. Every time I try and install Windows XP I get an error.

My operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium. I own a Dell Studio 1745 and have tried this a few times but keep getting a BSOD.

> Check for viruses on your computer. Remove any newly installed hard drives or hard drive controllers. Check your hard drive to make sure its properly configured . Run CHKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruption.
>
> Technical error information
>
> ...STOP: 0X0000007B C0XF78D2524, 0XC0000034, 0X00000000, 0X00000000.

How can I fix this?

Comment: .. and the error is  ?

Comment: look he googled the error code...XD

Comment: @Mark, please read http://superuser.com/faq We're not a forum, and you're making a big mess here. Please remove the "answer" you posted, and use the "edit" link of your question (and its title please!) instead. If "Ankur Dholakiya" is you too, then please click "flag" to ask a moderator to merge your accounts. Thanks! After that: enjoy!

Comment: Mark, do you want to REPLACE the existing Windows installation, or do you want to ADD windows XP as a second boot option?

Comment: Post your partition structure, screenshot of disk management please.

Comment: You're getting the BSOD because your laptop uses a SATA hard drive, and your Windows XP CD doesn't have the necessary controllers.  You'll need to provide them to the Windows XP installer somehow -- this requires either slipstreaming the drivers and building a new CD or a floppy drive, which your laptop doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

See method 2 for the proper way to install XP after W7 is already installed

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/8057-dual-boot-installation-windows-7-xp.html

.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to install Windows XP alongside Windows 7?  Unless you have a very particular use case that requires dual-booting into XP, nearly anything you would want to run or do in XP can be done in Win7.  If not, running XP in a virtual machine via XP Mode/Virtual PC, VMware, or VirtualBox will let you do just about everything else.

Between compatibility flags and VMs, there's virtually no reason to want to dual boot an older version of Windows.

Answer (score -2):

You are not able to install Windows XP becuase you've already installed Windows 7. Windows doesn't allow me install lower version OS over Higher version OS. Follw below steps to Resolve.

> > Boot computer with Windows XP CD.
> >     On partioning page Format your Drive which has Windows 7 installed.
> >     Continue setup.

Let me know if any issue or missing. I will re-post.

Comment: If you're the question asker "Mark", then please see my comments below the question. If not, then what does this answer mean?

Comment: Careful! This answer seems to suggest to format the the Windows 7 partition - sounds like a bad idea, and probably not what the asker wanted.